# Is there a way to ignore comments and whitespaces for FileLength check in Checkstyle

Tags: checkstyle

I am new to checkstyle and have spent good enough time on something which i believe should be an easy kill. I want to put a check on the number of lines in my file, which i successfully did. However i am not able to configure checkstyle to ignore empty lines as well as Java Comments before throwing in an error about Size Violations.

Reading their documentation i am of the view that FileLength module doesn't have any property that can be used to ignore comments and whitespaces. Here is the link and the sample code
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html

```
<module name="FileLength">
  <property name="max" value="500"/>
```

The only other exposed property is *fileExtensions*. Can someone please suggest what is the best way to put a tap on fileSize as well as not to discourage developers from putting in detailed documents?

Comment: Checkstyle project is considering to add support for Comments validation , please support  proposals at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/checkstyle/VEVFDsZKLzg

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. First off, there is no way to configure the *FileLength* check in the way that you need. It simply goes for the number of lines, including everything like a mandatory copyright statement header or whatnot.

So, what I do is this:

- Put a *FileLength* check with a really large number of lines, like 1500, so that even a very well commented file should not legally reach that limit.
- Use *ExecutableStatementCount* to limit methods to a certain number of statements. This would exclude comments and formatting which puts braces on lines of their own. In my experience, a good value here is 60. *MethodLength* can now be disabled.
- Use *MethodCount* to limit the number of methods.

Now, by multiplying the values of *MethodCount* and *ExecutableStatementCount*, you get a limit like you described, which is a limit on the number of statements per class, instead of a limit on the number of lines.

The actual values will have to undergo some tuning, so be prepared to change them a few times during your project.